# Ruby 1.9.3 regular expressions with gsub: Bugs or features?

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

Take this snippet of code which is supposed to replace a href tag with its URL:

```
irb> s='<p><a href="http://localhost/activate/57f7e805827f" style="color:#F19300;font-weight:bold">Click here!</a></p>'
irb> s.gsub(/<a href="([^ '"]*)"([^>]*)?>([^<]*)<\/a>/, "#{$1}")
=> "<p></p>"
```

This regex fails (URL is not found). Then I escape the `<` character in the regex, and it works:

```
irb> s.gsub(/<a href="([^ '"]*)"([^>]*)?>([^\<]*)<\/a>/, "#{$1}")
=> "<p>http://localhost/activate/57f7e805827f</p>"
```

**1:** According to RubyMine's inspections, this escape should not be necessary. Is this correct? If so, why is the escape of `>` apparently not necessary as well?

**2:** Afterwards in the same IRB session, with the same string, the original regex suddenly works too:

```
irb> s.gsub(/<a href="([^ '"]*)"([^>]*)?>([^<]*)<\/a>/, "#{$1}")
=> "<p>http://localhost/activate/57f7e805827f</p>"
```

Is this because the `$1` variable is not cleared when calling `gsub` again? If so, is it intentional behaviour or is this a Ruby regex bug?

**3:** When I change the string, and reexecute the same command, `$1` will only change after calling `gsub` twice on the changed string:

```
irb> s='<p><a href="http://localhost/activate/xxxxyyy" style="color:#F19300;font-weight:bold">Click here!</a></p>'
=> "<p><a href=\"http://localhost/activate/xxxxyyy\" style=\"color:#F19300;font-weight:bold\">Click here!</a></p>"
irb> s.gsub(/<a href="([^ '"]*)"([^>]*)?>([^\<]*)<\/a>/, "#{$1}")
=> "<p>http://localhost/activate/57f7e805827f</p>"
irb> s.gsub(/<a href="([^ '"]*)"([^>]*)?>([^\<]*)<\/a>/, "#{$1}")
=> "<p>http://localhost/activate/xxxxyyy</p>"
```

Is this intentional? If so, what is the logic behind this?

**4:** As replacement character, some tutorials suggest using `"#{$n}"`, others suggest using `'\n'`. With the backslash variant, the problems above do not appear. Why - what is the difference between the two?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$1` contains the first capture of the last match. In your example, it is evaluated *before* the matching (actually even before `gsub` is called), therefore the value of `$1` is fixed to `nil` (because you did not match anything, yet). So you always get the first capture of the *previous* match, you do not even need to change your original regex to get the expected result the second time:

```
s='<p><a href="http://localhost/activate/57f7e805827f" style="color:#F19300;font-weight:bold">Click here!</a></p>'

s.gsub(/<a href="([^ '"]*)"([^>]*)?>([^<]*)<\/a>/, "#{$1}")
# => "<p></p>"

s.gsub(/<a href="([^ '"]*)"([^>]*)?>([^<]*)<\/a>/, "#{$1}")
# => "<p>http://localhost/activate/57f7e805827f</p>"
```

You can pass a block to `gsub` though, which is evaluated *after* the matching, e. g.

```
s.gsub(/<a href="([^ '"]*)"([^>]*)?>([^<]*)<\/a>/){ $1 }
# => "<p>http://localhost/activate/57f7e805827f</p>"
```

This way, `$1` behaves as you'd expect. I like to always use named captures so i don't have to keep track of the numbers when i add a capture, though:

```
s.gsub(/<a href="(?<href>([^ '"]*))"([^>]*)?>([^<]*)<\/a>/){ $~[:href] }
# => "<p>http://localhost/activate/57f7e805827f</p>"
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes total sense.